# Possible to actually catch next-auth server side errors?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a large and very active website which uses next-auth for authentication

We notice a lot of errors spamming our logs - various issues where users may not have cookies enabled ('State cookie was missing'), or their system clock is off/they have let their JWT expire ('"exp" claim timestamp check failed')

Anyway - we rarely seem to also see a *lot* of these errors just before one of our web server shards fails. We can't actually rule out that this could be a sort of attack vector for bad actors to try and harm our site's uptime (though I assume with next-auth being used so heavily across the web this wouldn't be a thing that would go un-fixed for this long...)

Is there any way to actually catch these errors and handle them better? Or if that's not the cause of the crash, just not fill our logs with crazy amounts of spam which obfuscates our ability to find the root cause of the crash? Ideally when this happens, we could at least tell the user 'cookies must be enabled' or 'check your system clock' for a better UX...

I've tried wrapping the `NextAuth(...)(req,res)` in a try/catch within our route handler but that doesn't seem to stop the madness.

Any help is appreciated!